# Firebase Crashlytics record error/log etc not showing on console

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The following code errors are not showing on firebase console for some reason:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.log('This is brilliant log!');
                  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCustomKey('str_key', 'hello buffallo');
                  try {
                   throw 'error_example';
                  } catch (e, s) {
                   FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, s);
                  }
                  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
                      'No error',
                      StackTrace.empty,
                      reason: 'a non-fatal error',
                  );
```

However, when I force a crash i.e. use

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash()
```

This shows up fine! Is there something I am doing wrong?

I am using this version in pub spec: **firebase_crashlytics: ^0.4.0+1**
I can't use the latest version because of some external dependencies (before you ask)

Comment: For me unlike iOS it was sent after application restart. 'r' and 'R' for reload did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The errors recorded by `recordError` are listed as non-fatal exceptions in the Firebase console. At least for iOS they are only uploaded when the app was killed and reopened.